# How to cancel a ListPreference click?

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I have 3 preference settings:
- An EditTextPreference to enter a web address
- An EditTextPreference to enter a port
- A ListPreference to show some elements from the web page (e.g. http://www.igs-ip.net:2101) defined by the previous 2 settings.

To make this viable, I was thinking to validate the web connection on the click of the 3rd setting.  So far, I was able to catch the click to dynamically fill the ListPreference:

```
ListPreferenceDynamic dlp = (ListPreferenceDynamic)findPreference(strKey);
dlp.setOnClickListner(new ListPreferenceDynamicOnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(ListPreferenceDynamic preference) 
    {
        String[] astr = astrOpenWebPageAndGetInfo(strAddress, strPort);

        if (astr != null)
        {                           
            preference.setEntries(astr);                    
            preference.setEntryValues(astr);
        }
    }
});
```

My problem now is to find a way to prevent to show the ListPreference dialog when there is a problem, let say, with the internet address.  I would like only to show a Toast to explain the problem without showing an empty ListPreference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe still useful to some of you:

I figured that the OnPreferenceChangeListener can deal with that. Just register one and return true if you want accept the new value or return false if you want to cancel the click:

```
yourPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {

    if(condition){
        showToast();
        return false;        //cancel the click
    } 
    else return true;        //accept the click
});
```

The parameter *newValue* determines the new would-be value of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually after this.

But the ChangeListener triggers after a new value is picked, right?

So it's not really canceling the list which is what I'm after.

I did found a solution which was making a custom ListPreference class and conditionally handle the onClick.
That way if it's set as not active throught the setActive method the list will not show after clicking the option.

```
public class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {

private boolean isActive;

public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public boolean getActive() {
    return this.isActive;
}

@Override
public void onClick() {
    if (isActive) super.onClick();
}
}
```